# Unsure of why java/spring app is not saving my entity properly to MySQL database (when it is correctly saving another)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I've gone through most or all the StackOverflow questions relating to this question, and I haven't seen an answer that solves my problem.
I have this basic app that saves two different types of entities to a database (User and Quote). I am able to save the User entity just fine, but the Quote entity is not getting saved.

**App Controller**

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired 
    private QuoteRepository quoteRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String viewRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        User newUser = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", newUser);
        return "signup_form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/processRegister")
    public String processRegister(User user) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
    
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "register_success";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String listUsers(Model model) {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "list_users";
    }

    @GetMapping("/quotes")
    public String listQuotes(Model model) {
        List<Quote> quotes = quoteRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("quotes", quotes);
        return "quotes/list_quotes";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormToAddQuote")
    public String showFormToAddQuote(Model model) {
        Quote quote = new Quote();
        model.addAttribute("quote", quote);
        return "quotes/add_quote";
    }

    @PostMapping("/processQuote")
    public String processQuote(@ModelAttribute("quote") Quote quote) {
        quoteRepository.save(quote);
        return "redirect:/quotes";
    }
}
```

**User Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

   @Id 
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="id")
   private Long id;
 
   @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45)
   private String email;
 
   @Column(nullable = false, length = 64)
   private String password;
 
   @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
   private String firstName;
 
   @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
   private String lastName;

   public User() {}

   public User(Long id, String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName) {
       this.id = id;
       this.email = email;
       this.password = password;
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   // getters and setters                                                                                       
}
```

**User Repository Class**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email")
    public User findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

}
```

**Quote Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="quote")
public class Quote {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="quote")
    private String quote;
    
    @Column(name="quotee")
    private String quotee;
    
    @Column(name="found_in")
    private String foundIn;
    
    public Quote() {}

    public Quote(int id, String quote, String quotee, String foundIn) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.quote = quote;
        this.quotee = quotee;
        this.foundIn = foundIn;
    }

    // getters and setters  
}
```

**Quote Repository Class**

```
public interface QuoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Quote, Integer> {

}
```

Using Thymeleaf syntax for html forms:

**List Quotes HTML**

```
<div class="container text-center"> 
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead class="table-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Quote</th>
                <th>Quotee</th>
                <th>Found In</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="quote: ${quotes}">
                <td th:text="${quote.quote}">Quote</td>
                <td th:text="${quote.quotee}">Quotee</td>
                <td th:text="${quote.foundIn}">Found In</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Add Quote Form HTML**

```
<form th:action="@{/processQuote}" th:object="${quote}"
   method="POST" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
            
   <input type="text" th:field="*{quote}"
      class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Quote" required>
   <input type="text" th:field="*{quotee}"
      class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Quotee">
   <input type="text" th:field="*{foundIn}"
      class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Source (Found In)">
            
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

I excluded imports, package names, and getters/setters. It seems that spring is trying to convert my string input corresponding to the 'quote' column of the table into an in Integer even though the field is of type String.

**Stack Trace**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.maria.springboot.quoterepo.entity.Quote'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'Life isn't about finding yourself. Life is about creating yourself.'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Lifeisn'taboutfindingyourself.Lifeisaboutcreatingyourself."
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.maria.springboot.quoterepo.entity.Quote'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'Life isn't about finding yourself. Life is about creating yourself.'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Lifeisn'taboutfindingyourself.Lifeisaboutcreatingyourself."
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:79)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:53)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttributeFromRequestValue(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:237)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'Life isn't about finding yourself. Life is about creating yourself.'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Lifeisn'taboutfindingyourself.Lifeisaboutcreatingyourself."
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter$ToEntityConverter.convert(DomainClassConverter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter.lambda$convert$0(DomainClassConverter.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter.convert(DomainClassConverter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Lifeisn'taboutfindingyourself.Lifeisaboutcreatingyourself."
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:660)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:991)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:211)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterFactoryAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:437)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    ... 109 more
```

Comment: To avoid these kinds of problems, I never use an entity directly in Thymeleaf. I use a dedicated FormData class to model the interaction with the form so I can keep my entity clean. See https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/ for detailed info on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Lifeisn'taboutfindingyourself.Lifeisaboutcreatingyourself."
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:660)
```

This is the causing issue - it can't parse `"Lifeisn'taboutfindingyourself.Lifeisaboutcreatingyourself."` into an integer.

My guess is that it is happenning because you don't have a constructor for Quote that expects 3 Strings so Thymeleaf picks the one with all arguments including Id and tries to convert the first parameter into an Integer.

Try creating the right constructor:

```
public Quote(String quote, String quotee, String foundIn) {
    this.quote = quote;
    this.quotee = quotee;
    this.foundIn = foundIn;
}
```

Also make sure all the setters are also present - important for thymeleaf

Comment: I changed the constructor by removing the 'id' parameter but unfortunately the same exception is thrown.

Comment: Well we know it happens in the Controller, in the processQuote method - can you try setting a debugger there?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Wrapper` type for your `id` property in `Quote` entity instead of primitives. As follows

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="quote")
public class Quote {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id; // <--- Change from `int` to Long
...
...

}
```